# ggplot: grouped bar plot - alpha value & legend per group

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have data with two data points for an observation (indicated by the unique `pty`/`time` combination in `res`), which I would like to plot as barplot.

Consider this toy data:

```
df <- data.frame(pty = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
       print_col = c("#FFFF00", "#FFFF00", "#000000", "#000000", "#ED1B34", "#ED1B34"),
       time = c(2020,2016,2020,2016,2020,2016),
       res = c(20,35,30,35,40,45))
```

I am using `ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(pty, res , fill = as.factor(pty), group=as.factor(time)),  position = "dodge", stat = "summary" , fun = "mean")` to plot this with the following result (s. below).

[image: bar plot]

However, I would like to alter two things:

1. coloring: (i) the bar colors should be taken from the column `print_col` for the respective row and (ii) for `time==2016`, I want an `alpha` value of `.5` for better readability.
2. legend: the `fill` legend is unnecessary. Instead, I want the legend for `group` (i.e. "Time" as title and "2020" / "2016" as entries).

I couldn't figure out a way to achieve these - can someone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an alpha is as simple as mapping a column to the `alpha` aesthetic, which gives you a legend by default. Using `fill = I(print_col)` automatically sets an 'identity' fill scale, which hides the legend by default.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(pty = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
                 print_col = c("#FFFF00", "#FFFF00", "#000000", "#000000", "#ED1B34", "#ED1B34"),
                 time = c(2020,2016,2020,2016,2020,2016),
                 res = c(20,35,30,35,40,45))


ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(pty, res, fill = I(print_col), group = time,
               alpha = as.factor(time)),
           position = "dodge", stat = "summary", fun = "mean") +
  # You can tweak the alpha values with a scale
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.3, 0.7))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Awesome, thank you! How would I alter `as.factor(time)` to `Time`, `2016` to `Year 1 (2016)`, and `2020` to `Year 1 (2020)`?

Comment: You can use the `name` and `labels` argument of the scale. For example `scale_alpha_manual(name = "Time", labels = c("Year 1 (2016)", "Year 2 (2020)"))`.

Answer (score 1):

another way is to add alpha to the dataset and call it in the `alpha` parameter. in the `scale_alpha()` I hide the legend so you don't have to see two legends and only keep the one in your original example . I also call the unique values for the colors in the `scale_fill_manual()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(pty = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
                 print_col = c("#FFFF00", "#FFFF00", "#000000", "#000000", "#ED1B34", "#ED1B34"),
                 time = c(2020,2016,2020,2016,2020,2016),
                 res = c(20,35,30,35,40,45))

df <- mutate(df, alph = ifelse(time ==2016 , .5,1))

 ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(pty, res , fill = as.factor(pty), group=as.factor(time), alpha = alph),
                      position = "dodge", stat = "summary" , fun = "mean")+
              scale_fill_manual("pty", values  = unique(df$print_col))+
              scale_alpha(guide = "none")
```

[image]